# Having issues troubleshooting this error: Unparseable date: "June 17, 1985 11:33:00 UTC"

Tags: java, android, json, date, simpledateformat

This appears to only occur on a small portion of my users devices, I cannot reproduce this issue but its blowing up my Crashlytics reports.

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "June 17, 1985 11:33:00 UTC" (at offset 0)
   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
   at me.calebjones.spacelaunchnow.content.services.LaunchDataService.parsePreviousResult(LaunchDataService.java:548)
   at me.calebjones.spacelaunchnow.content.services.LaunchDataService.getPreviousLaunches(LaunchDataService.java:243)
   at me.calebjones.spacelaunchnow.content.services.LaunchDataService.onHandleIntent(LaunchDataService.java:115)
   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

There's multiple dates that it seems to get stuck on however they are all in the same format. Here's my code for parsing it.

```
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy kk:mm:ss zzz");
        df.toLocalizedPattern();

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray launchesArray = response.optJSONArray("launches");

        for (int i = 0; i < launchesArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                launch.setLaunchDate(df.parse(launchesObj.optString("net")));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                launch.setLaunchDate(null);
            }
        }
```

Feel free to take a look at the source here: https://github.com/caman9119/SpaceLaunchNow/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/me/calebjones/spacelaunchnow/content/services/LaunchDataService.java

Comment: You should really set the locale on your format object to make sure that it can parse English month names. Maybe the device locale is not set to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the locale fixed the issue.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy kk:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US);
```